# Array of structs: Incompatible parameter types

Tags: c, arrays, struct

This is the first time I am making an array of structs. Basically I am trying to make a sort of histogram. That is analyze the string I provide and print out which letter has the most occurrences. Also I want to say that my program does work! I get all the right results. But when the program finishes the calculations and displays them it crashes. And I am left with an error saying

```
IntelliSense: argument of type "Occurrences **" is incompatible with parameter of type "Occurrences *"
```

for this line of code:

```
maximum_occurrences(str, ch, num, arr1);
```

which is located in my `main.c`. I will try to provide all of the code necessary below. Any ideas on how to fix the crash at the end would be very appreciated, but again the program logic works perfect! :) Thanks also I am a novice coder (1 semester in C).

Main:

```
int main ()
{
    // Introduced the original string which as a pointer.
    // Introduced the original character pointer 'ch'. (Set to an arbitrary Character.)
    // Introduced the original int pointer as 'num'. (Set to an arbitrary integer.)
    char *str = {"hey my name is dillon johnson im in comp sci"}, *ch = '\0';
    int *num = 0;

    struct Occurrences *arr1[25];

    // Calling the max occurrences function.
    maximum_occurrences(str, ch, num, arr1);

    return 0; 
}
```

Header:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct occurrences
{
    int num_occurrences;
    double frequency;
}Occurrences;

void maximum_occurrences (char *str, char *chPtr, int *num, Occurrences *arr1);
```

Source.c:

```
void maximum_occurrences(char *str, char *chPtr, int *num, Occurrences *arr1)
{
    char stringp = *str;
    int i = 0, j = 0, strLength = 0, temp, max = 0, k = 0;
    double frequency = 0;
    char maxch = ' ';

    // Setting strLength to the length of the alpha string.
    strLength = strlen(str);

    for (k = 0; k < 25; k++)
    {
        arr1[k].num_occurrences = 0;
    }

    // Displaying to the user what sentance will be used for the program.
    printf ("%s%s", "The given sentence is: ", str);
    printf ("\n");

    // The algorithm to determine which characters occur multiple times.
    // I am using a for loop to first parse through the array and then when
    // each letter occurs I subtract 97 from the ascii value. The resulting
    // Integer will be the corresponding place in the array of struct Occurrences
    // where that particular variable is held.

    for (i = 0; i < strLength; i++)
    {
        temp = (str[i] - 97); // temp is now set to an integer value that is the correspoinding position in the array of structs.
        (int)arr1[temp].num_occurrences = (int)arr1[temp].num_occurrences + 1; // Increases the number of occurrences in the specific struct by one to represnt
                                                                     // a single occurrence of that character.
    }

    for (j = 0; j < 26; j++)                    // This finds the maximum amount of occurrences and then continues to mach that value
    {                                           // to a character by adding 97 to the index of the array to acheive the appropriate ascii value
        if (max < arr1[j].num_occurrences)
        {
            max = arr1[j].num_occurrences;
            maxch = j + 97;
        }
    }

    frequency = ((double)max / (double)strLength); // Calculating the frequency of the most common character

    printf ("%s%c%s%d%s%.3lf%s", "The letter '", maxch,"' occurred the most, occurring ", max, " times, with a frequency of: ", frequency,".\n");

    return;
}
```

Comment: You should pass the size of the array to the function, rather than writing `25` in the function.  There is way too much 'coupling' between the `main()` function and the `maximum_occurrences()` otherwise.  Which language are you using that has a 25-letter alphabet — or what happens when the string is "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"?  Using 97 instead of `'a'` is a bad idea.  You should probably check that the character is lower-case alphabetic before doing the calculation, and maybe convert upper-case to lower-case, ignoring non-alphabetic characters.  You string contains spaces!

Comment: Note that you've not allocated the space for the array of pointers to point at.  You almost certainly want a simple array of structures (of size 26) rather than array of (uninitialized) pointers to structures.

Comment: `struct Occurrences *arr1[25];` is an array of pointers to struct, not an array of structs. Remove the `*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is exactly what the error message is telling you. Learn to interpret the compiler errors and life will be much easier for you...

`arr1` is an array of 25 pointers to Occurrences structures.

`maximum_occurrences` expects one `Occurrences*`, not an array of them.

Therefore you can't pass `arr1` to `maximum_occurrences()`.

**Based on discussion via comments:**

In main() you have `struct Occurrences* arr1[25];` — an array of 25 pointers to Occurrences (Occurrences*). You never allocate any Occurrences, so even if it did compile, it's not going to work.

You want 25 Occurrences (not pointers) — `struct Occurrences arr1[25];` — and now you should be able to use `max_occurrences` as is. Note that it is bad practice to have `max_occurrences` assume a length of 25 — you should pass the length into it.

Last but not least, if you want 1 Occurrence per letter, you need an array of 26 (which gives you indexes 0-25)

Comment: thanks for your quick response. So would I have to change `void maximum_occurrences(char *str, char *chPtr, int *num, Occurrences *arr1)` to `void maximum_occurrences(char *str, char *chPtr, int *num, Occurrences arr1[25])` Or am I just completely off, I am not very good at syntax I apologize.

Comment: Nope, your 2nd attempt is has `max_occs` taking an array of 25 objects. `arr1` is an array of 25 pointers to objects. You've still trying to get a square peg into that round hole... Ar you sure `arr1` is supposed to be an array of pointers and not an array of objects?

Comment: arr1 is supposed to be a pointer to an array of 25 struct occurrences. Really confusing at least for me. But I think what my proph was getting at is that he wants 1 struct for each letter. If that makes sense.

Comment: So you don't need `struct Occurrences *arr1[25];` in main. Write it like this and it might be a bit clearer what you currently have `struct Occurrences* arr1[25];` - You have an array of 25 pointers. You want an array of 25 objects. `struct Occurrences arr1[25];`

Comment: Ah I can now see I am way in over my head haha. Thanks for all your help but I think this would take much longer for me to figure out what is wrong. I will try to seek assistance at my college tomorrow. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to change the function to

```
void maximum_occurrences(char *str, char *chPtr, int *num, Occurrences **arr1, int arrsize){
//..
for (k = 0; k < arrsize; k++)
    {
        arr1[k]->num_occurrences = 0;
    }
//..
for (j = 0; j < arrsize; j++)                    // This finds the maximum amount of occurrences and then continues to mach that value
    {                                           // to a character by adding 97 to the index of the array to acheive the appropriate ascii value
        if (max < arr1[j]->num_occurrences)
        {
            max = arr1[j]->num_occurrences;
            maxch = j + 97;


       }
        //..
}
```

And then call it with

```
maximum_occurrences(str, ch, num, arr1, 25);
```

Also, don't forget to allocate the memory for `arr1` prior to calling `maximum_occurrences()` using `malloc(sizeof(struct Occurrences))` for each array element.

Comment: Where is the space for each `Occurrences` structure allocated?  At the moment, it is done nowhere...in your code or the original.  It might be better to change the type in the `main` to `Occurrences arr1[26];` (allowing for an orthodox 26-letter alphabet).